# compressing the large files using gzip - ie8 and above

Tags: java, javascript, internet-explorer, gzip

I have some very large files (XML / CSV) which client (IE8 and above) needs to download and process.  Before I invest too much time on to it, I wanted to ask if it would be feasible to use gzip compression to do this?  From this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837251) it looks like it would not work out of box for IE without installing an exe/or changing internet settings (which doesnt work for me because this will go to 1000s of users).

Second question is if IE doesnt support it what other browsers support it unconditionally- I am specifically interested in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it worked for me on IE8 as well.